# Haskell List comprehensions infinite list problem

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, infinite, hamming-numbers, smooth-numbers

I'm trying to learn Haskell and comprehension lists but cannot find solution on this:

```
mylist = [x*y | x <- [1..], y <- [1..]]
```

After my trials the result is something like this

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,...]
```

because in list comprehensions, `x` takes the value `1`,and then `y` changes value repeatedly.

But my goal is to achieve a different assignment so as to have the following result:

```
mylist = [1,2,2,4,3,3,6.....]
```

I mean i want the combinations being mixed and not each one apart,because I have a serious problem to have the suitable result.

I will give a more specific example.

I want a list that will have all numbers of this form:

```
num = 2^x * 3^y
```

`x` and `y` must take all values `>= 0`.

My approach is the following:

```
powers = [2^x * 3^y | x <- [0..], y <- [0..]]
```

But in this way I only take powers of 3, because `x` is constantly 0.

I tried this one

```
multiples = nub (merge (<=) powers2 powers3)
powers3 = [2^x * 3^y | x <- [0..], y <- [0..]]
powers2 = [2^x * 3^y | y <- [0..], x <- [0..]]
```

so as to merge the different ones but again,the values 6,12,etc. are missing - the result is this:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,8,9,16,27,32,64,81...]
```

Comment: So it's just a matter of ordering? I wonder if `[x*y | (x,y) <- zip [1..] [1..]]` would work? Hm, yeah no, that actually goes on both at the same time. Interesting question actually.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Just prepending `sort` does the trick for finite lists.

Comment: If you arrange all values `x, y` on a two-dimensional grid, can you show the path in which you intend to iterate through them?

Comment: How about powers3=[2^x*3^y | x <-[0..],y <-[0..x]]     Then you can sort the resulting list.

Comment: Getting things in a different order is easy. But "mixed" is not an order. If you can specify precisely what order you want, we'll be able to help a lot better.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo increasing order.

Comment: Maybe this question should be tagged [sorting], but there are already too many tags.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it's not exactly sorting. I have tried for example to make 2 different lists as I writed on the post and mergesort between them but I'm missing results.       The problem is on the multiplying.For example for values x=2,y=1, the result will be 2^2*3^1 = 12. In the above case I 'm missing this result. I just want to take the numbers sorted finally,but I guess it's not possible to sort an infinite list.

Comment: I don't understand. It's not sorting, but you tried to mergesort? Can you explain the logic by which the result should be ordered? (See my [earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095052/haskell-list-comprehensions-infinite-list-problem?noredirect=1#comment95022948_54095052))

Comment: @mkrieger1 simple increasing order. you probably meant merge, not mergesort. @ Jam-aica yes it can be done. there's a package data-ordlist; and the two tags that I added have many highly relevant entries. :)

Comment: OK,I tried the solution of @MatteoUgolotti and that helped but I've not totally solved it.                                                                                                                                            powers2=[2^x*3^y | y <-[0..],x <-[0..y]]
powers3=[2^x*3^y | x <-[0..],y <-[0..x]]                                                                             multiples = nub (merge (<=) powers2 powers3) But merge does not do the job totally.

Comment: @mkrieger1 re "readily known path" this is a not yet solved problem AFAIK. I can explain it by I can't code it. the explanation is: in the 2D grid, draw a line from (1/log 2,0) to (0,1/log 3). Now move it away from (0,0) keeping it parallel to itself. As you come to cross each (i,j) point for whole i and j, output `2^i*3^j`.

Comment: @JAMAICA our last two streams, [2^x*3^y | y <-[0..],x <-[0..y]]  and the other one, won't be ordered. but merge needs its arguments ordered. that's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you show,

```
multiples = nub (merge (<=) powers2 powers3)
powers3 = [2^x * 3^y | x <- [0..], y <- [0..]]
powers2 = [2^x * 3^y | y <- [0..], x <- [0..]]
```

is equivalent to

```
powers3 = [2^x * 3^y | x <- [0], y <- [0..]]
        = [2^0 * 3^y | y <- [0..]]
        = [3^y | y <- [0..]]
powers2 = [2^x * 3^y | y <- [0], x <- [0..]] 
        = [2^x * 3^0 | x <- [0..]]
        = [2^x | x <- [0..]]
```

so you only produce the powers of *2* and *3*, without any mixed multiples. As such, there are guaranteed to be no duplicates in the stream, and the `nub` was not necessary. And of course it's incomplete.

But let's look at it at another angle. It was proposed in the comments to create a 2D grid out of these numbers:

```
mults23_2D = [[2^x * 3^y | y <- [0..]] | x <- [0..]]
{-
   1   3   9   27  81  ...
   2   6  18   54  ...
   4  12  36  108  ...
   8  24  72  ...
  16  ...
  .......     
-}
```

Now we're getting somewhere. At least now none are skipped. We just need to understand how to *join* them into one sorted, increasing stream of numbers. Simple `concat` of course won't do. We need to merge them in order. A well-known function `merge` does that, provided the arguments are already ordered, increasing lists.

Each row produced is already in increasing order, but there are infinitely many of them. Never fear, `foldr` can do it. We define

```
mults23 = foldr g [] [[2^x * 3^y | y <- [0..]] | x <- [0..]]
  -- foldr g [] [a,b,c,...] == a `g` (b `g` (c `g` (....)))
 where
 g (x:xs) ys =
```

Here it is a little bit tricky. If we define `g = merge`, we'll have a run-away recursion, because each `merge` will want to know the head element of its "right" (second) argument stream.

To prevent that, we produce the leftmost element right away.

```
                x : merge xs ys
```

And that's that.

Comment: Bingo! That worked. Make no mistake,the lists I wrote were not the ones you pointed out at start, it was the same with mults23_2D but I had not managed to make that kind of sorting! How could I handle it If I wanted to add in the equation 5^z?( 2^x*3^y*5^z)

Comment: To add 5^z like in the above comment,we just need a double nested foldr...       
                                                                                                                             
result = foldr g [] [foldr g....]

Answer (score 0):

**Tool use**

I needed an infinite Cartesian product function. An infinite function must take the diagonals of a table.
The pair pattern of a diagonal traversal is

0 0 – 0 1, 1 0 – 0 2, 1 1, 2 0 – 0 3, 1 2, 2 1, 3 0

I love the symmetries but the pattern is counting forward with first digit and backward with second which when expressed in an infinite function is

```
diag2 xs ys = [ (m,n) | i<- [1..], (m,n) <- zip (take i xs) (reverse.take i $ ys) ]
```

The infinite generation is just to take any amount however large to work with.
What may be important, also is taking a diagonal or triangular number for a complete set.
`revt n` makes a triangular number from you input.  If you want 25 elements `revt 25` will return 7. `tri 7` will return 28 the parameter for `take`. `revt` and `tri` are

```
tri n = foldl (+) 1 [2..n]
revt n = floor (sqrt (n*2))
```

Making and using `taket` is good until you learn the first 10 or so triangular numbers.

```
taket n xs = take (tri $ revt n) xs
```

Now, with some tools in place we apply them (mostly 1) to a problem.

```
[ 2^a * 3^b | (a,b) <- sort.taket 25 $ diag2 [0..] [0..]]
```

[1,3,9,27,81,243,729, 2,6,18,54,162,486, 4,12,36,108,324, 8,24,72,216, 16,48,144, 32,96, 64]

And it’s a diagonal. The first group is 7 long, the second is 6 long, the second-to-the-last is 2 long and the last is 1 long. `revt 25` is 7. `tri 7` is 28 the length of the output list.